# Routing php requests with nginx using fastcgi results in 404 error

Tags: php, magento, nginx, zend-framework, fastcgi

I'm new to nginx and want to configure it so the user can access URLs like

http://[ip_address]/dev/index.php/customer/account/login/

I think this may be related to using FastCGI to process the request and pass it to Magento. However, whenever I access it, i see a 404 message. I can confirm that the user running nginx and owning the directory and files is www-data. So it has access to it. I need help configuring nginx & FastCGI properly so the request loads the correct page.
All of my application is in dev/ folder. Here's the relevant chunk of default file in /etc/nginx/sites-available/defaul:

```
        root /var/www;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _ test.xxx.com;



           location /dev/ {
                    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
           }

           location /dev/app/ {
                    deny all;
            }

           location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                    # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
                    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            }
```

Comment: Why do you want your website to have a url structure with `index.php` in the middle of the uri? Where on your filesystem are you hoping Nginx is going to serve files from in response to this request?¿?

Comment: I'm using Magento, which uses Zend Framework. The url above will be translated to look for dev/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Account/Model/Customer.php file

Answer (score -1):

Here is my nginx config. May help you.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 900;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```